# Delete row if cells equal a set of values

Tags: excel, vba, row, delete-row

I created a macro to in order to generate a daily report. The portion of the macro that finds a value in column AN and deletes the entire row (code edited to delete rows starting from the last used row), works well. 
The following example deletes all the rows that **do not** contain the value "CAT","BAT", or "DOG in column AN.

```
'False screen updating
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'deleting all other types other than CAT from "samples" tab (excluding the header row, row 1)
  Sheets("sample").Select
  Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row
'Deleting rows from bottom up
    For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If Range("AN" & i).Value <> "CAT" And _
           Range("AN" & i).Value <> "BAT" And _
           Range("AN" & i).Value <> "DOG" Then
             Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

However, would like to create another Sub that deletes all the rows that **do** contain a specific set of values.
I tried **replacing <>** with **=** and **==**, however neither worked and no rows were deleted

Comment: Pro tip: delete from the bottom up, not the top down.  Try going from LastRowNum to 2 step -1. it simplifies your loop

Comment: While iterating backwards is a great tip, one could also opt to use Find a value in column AN untill value isn't found nomore. That way you won't have to iterate through all rows. That becomes handy on larger datasets. And, also avoid using Select. No need for that.

Comment: What is the specific set of values? Do those values also exist in column "AN"?

Comment: Possibility: You can drop the values you want to search for in an array. Loop through your array, using FindNext to get all rows per value. Use union to combine all found ranges into one so you can delete entire range at once. So you can prevent iterating through all cells and deleting row by row. It should speed up your proces.

Comment: @sous2817 would the code look something like this in order to delete from the bottom up? LastRowNum = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
 AND Range("AN"   & ReadRow). EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Comment: @JvdV Why Should I avoid using .Select? I had this in place since the entire Sub is actually switching between different sheets and running the same loop in each

Comment: @TateGarringer Yes column AN contains all the values that I would like to Delete (e.g. CAT, DOG, BAT, etc.)

Comment: @JvdV An array would work perfectly! However I am new to VBA and could not figure out how to create an array that worked correctly. Would you mind posting example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for help resolving this issue. I have found that the root cause of my problem was simply the condition statement at the end of my If/Then line. The "**And_**" statement was saying "If cell equals CAT and BAT and DOG, then delete row" NOT "If cell equals CAT or BAT or DOG, then delete row". Replacing "**And_**" with "**Or_**" has fixed this issue.

```
'False screen updating
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'deleting all other types other than CAT from "samples" tab (excluding the header row, row 1)
  Sheets("sample").Select
  Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row
'Deleting rows from bottom up
    For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If Range("AN" & i).Value = "CAT" Or _
           Range("AN" & i).Value = "BAT" Or _
           Range("AN" & i).Value = "DOG" Or _
           Range("AN" & i).Value = "" Then
             Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

However, I would also like to delete rows if the cells is **Blank ""**. Why would the Sub ignore this line?

```
  Range("AN" & i).Value = "" Then
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample how to delete rows based on a criteria in column A. Keep in mind that if we delete rows we go backwards to avoid index errors.

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Where you delete you go backwards
        For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "CAT" Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the great example for deleting rows from the bottom up. I will try this out to see how it improves. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the question to delete rows from bottom up. It worked great! Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to do it this way:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sample")
    i=1

    While sht.(i,1) <> "" 'Assuming first column is full of data to the bottom
        If sht.Range("AN" & i) = "CAT" Then
              sht.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            i=i+1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Never iterate forward deleting rows. Always backwards. Also you should avoid using integer. There simply isn't a reason to use a limited variable.

Comment: @JvdV Has a good point and this does not answer my initial question regarding how to delete rows that = CAT not <> CAT

Comment: No problem, you can simply swap out `<>` for `=`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @healey I tried simply replacing <> with = with limited success. I am really not sure why I can not just simply switch the code to delete rows NOT containing CAT to deleting all rows that DO contain CAT with = :(

Comment: @user223522, are you looking for cells where the value contains "CAT", or equals only "CAT"?

Comment: @healey Equals only "CAT", however I realized what the issue was...I should be using "Or_" not "And_"

Comment: @healey That issue has been resolved, however now the Sub will not delete rows with empty cells ("") in column AN...

Comment: Use an `OR` statement to detect blank cells in column AN:

`If sht.Range("AN" & i) = "CAT" Or sht.Range("AN" & i) = "" Then`

Answer (score 0):

A site that might be able to help you be the following.

https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/delete-rows-cell-values/
I adjusted the code a little.

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value()
'Apply a filter to a Range and delete visible rows
'Source: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/delete-rows-cell-values

    Dim ws As Worksheet

      'Set reference to the sheet in the workbook.
      Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sampel")
      ws.Activate 'not required but allows user to view sheet if warning message appears

      'Clear any existing filters
      On Error Resume Next
        ws.ShowAllData
      On Error GoTo 0

      '1. Apply Filter
      ws.Range("AN3:BG1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>CAT"

      '2. Delete Rows
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Range("B1:G1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True

      '3. Clear Filter
      On Error Resume Next
        ws.ShowAllData
      On Error GoTo 0

    End Sub
```

Comment: I am not really sure why you would use an Auto filter in VBA? I created the macro to avoid having to filer in order to delete rows

Comment: I find that using native worksheet functions a lot faster than loops. Normally I create a macro to avoid doing it manually not to avoid doing a specific task. Does it matter that the macro still filters if it gets the job done faster?

Comment: You may have a good point. I have not tried many native worksheet functions in my VBA. However I feel as though I will learn more basic programming skills by writing the loops myself.  Plus, this way code can be easily understood/edited in the future by not using too many ws functions.